# Babel and large files

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have one big javascript file and I want use babel on it. But file have around 100k lines (~2.8 MB) and I got message about limit to 500kb.

- I'm using babel-cli with preset 'env' on Windows (installed on machine, not web version)

Is there way to compile such big file with babel?

Comment: I realize it's stating the obvious, but: You *really, really* want to split that file up into parts (and then combine them for production).

Comment: Ok i give more information about problem. I got library which is not working on Internet Explorer 11 and I want to try solve problem in that way :)

If you know any good way to split javascript into smaller files in easy way (keeping structure) it would be helpful